# Custom activity and Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, custom-activity

- Is it possible to perform ampscript operations inside a custom activity?
- Can Postmonger perform ampscript operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot directly do that. It is an externally hosted application that communicates with SFMC via APIs. Hence all the complexity to the docs with hosting, iframes, authentication etc.

AMPscript on the other hand is native to SFMC and external apps won't run it.

See here (highlights by me):

> You need a custom activity for one of your journeys that kicks off a REST API call in a **third-party application**. Create an installed package with a Journey Builder Activity component. You can have multiple Journey Builder Activities per package.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/packages-overview.html

What you can do is try to communicate with a secured (cloudpage) handler page via API upon specific actions in your outside app. Living inside SFMC, that handler page could run AMPScript.

Comment: Thank you so much! You really helped me!